# Boo to the Chocolatey Gods

Tags: c#, git, powershell, command-line, chocolatey

**Update:**

This utility is to help configure *Git* through a certified Microsoft Visual Academy (MVA) video that I was going through.

I receive a peculiar error when I install packages through Chocolatey.

- I've uploaded Command Prompt
- Pointed directory to Chocolatey Bin Directory
- Attempt to install via `cinst poshgit`

It downloads and appears as if it is working, it even creates the directory under `C:\Tools\Poshgit`.  Then it gives me the following:

> [Error] Cannot bind arguement to parameter 'Path' because it is an
>   empty string.  At
>   C:\Chocolatey\ChocolateyInstall\Helpers\functions\Writer-ChocolateyFailure.ps1:30
>   char 2

Which resulted in a failure, I'm not entirely sure why either.  It is a fresh install of Chocolatey.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann The error actually includes "Boo to the Chocolatey gods!"

Comment: +1 FOR the title alone.

Comment: While "questions about general computing hardware and software" are off-topic, "software tools commonly used by programmers" are decidedly on-topic.  And git (and posh-git) are decidedly commonly used software tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So installing *Git* and *Posh-Git* hasn't been too pleasant, how I fixed the error was by reinstalling *Chocolatey*, then doing the following:

```
@Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
```

I know it is a tedious command, but I reinstalled with the above then did the following through *Power Shell* (Ran as Administrator).

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
cinst poshgit
```

That didn't fully resolve as there were reminents of the previous failure, so I did:

```
cinst poshgit -force
cinst git.install -force
git
```

Once I typed `git` I had access to the `git` commands and was able to:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "Your Email"
cinst git-credential-winstore
```

Without any additional problems, the issue derived from the *Command-Line* install, should of just started with *Power Shell*.