# Error during poshgit installation with windows powershell

Tags: git, powershell, installation

I am trying to install poshgit through chocolatey on a Japanese windows 7 Enterprise machine and running into install error.

I am using powershell 2.0 as administrator, and have set the execution policy to remotesigned.

Executing the command "cinst poshgit" I can see that git is first downloaded and installed without any problems.

Poshgit is then downloaded, and gives the following error during installation.

```
    poshgit v0.5.0.201401009
Downloading poshgit 64 bit
  from 'https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/zipball/master'
Extracting C:\Users\soukaei\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\poshgit\poshgitInstall.zip to C:\tools\poshgit...

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        11/17/2014     15:47            poshgit
C:\tools\poshgit
poshgit has finished successfully! The chocolatey gods have answered your request!
Write-Error : poshgit did not finish successfully. Boo to the chocolatey gods!
-----------------------
[ERROR] Unable to index into an object of type System.IO.DirectoryInfo.
-----------------------
At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\chocolateyinstall\helpers\functions\Write-ChocolateyFailure.ps1:30 char:14
+   Write-Error <<<<  $errorMessage
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Write-Error

Write-Error : Package 'poshgit v0.5.0.201401009' did not install successfully: Unable to index into an object of type S
ystem.IO.DirectoryInfo.
At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\chocolateyinstall\functions\Chocolatey-NuGet.ps1:90 char:28
+                 Write-Error <<<<  "Package `'$installedPackageName v$installedPackageVersion`' did not install succes
sfully: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Write-Error

Finished installing 'poshgit' and dependencies - if errors not shown in console, none detected. Check log for errors if
unsure.
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Not familiar with the problem specifically, but found some info over at [this blog.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PromptsAndDirectoriesEvenBetterGitAndMercurialWithPowerShell.aspx)

They have what looks like an alternate install method using PsGet: `(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
install-module posh-git`

No idea if that is a good idea or not.
Also might be worth checking [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434344/boo-to-the-chocolatey-gods) If neither help, it might be worth contacting poshgit support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information.

I've had no luck going the chocolatey route, so went for the manual method provided on the official website.

A git pull and running the set up gave me no errors and problem solved.